# Next frame WPF mediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

I am trying to create a video player using WPF.
I would like to create a button that jumps to the next frame in the video.
How can I do it with mediaElement control?

Comment: I don't recall seeing anything related to frame count in the MediaElement, but if you can get the FPS of the video, you should be able to increment the position by the correct number of milliseconds. This however won't work if the video is variable frame rate.

Comment: I don't believe you can.  The API isn't that low-level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow [this](http://www.jasonhales.co.uk/2015/01/wpf-frame-rate-calculator.html) guide to calculate FPS and then as TyCobb suggested you can increment the position like this

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(newSecond);
System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    mediaElement1.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(newSecond);
});
```

keep in mind to have

```
MediaElement.ScrubbingEnabled = True
```

Comment: Your note to use `.ScrubbingEnabled = True` saved me so much frustration. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but something is missing here: where does "newSecond" come from, and where is a  calculated fps used?

Comment: @oo_dev it is just a variable ...